# How to configure JaCoCo in a custom gradle plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, plugins

I am writing a custom Gradle plugin which shall unifiedly abstract from my custom gradle configurations which are spread across multiple Java projects. For this purpose, I generally try to find [fitting extensions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#reacting_to_plugins) for the various tasks that need custom configuration.

So, I got to the point where I wanted to move my [JaCoCo configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_report_configuration) to the plugin. The excerpt from build.gradle looks like this:

```groovy
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required = true
    }
}
```

The first part is manageable: check if the plugin is loaded.

```java
project.getPlugins().withType(JacocoPlugin.class, jacocoPlugin -> {
  // configure it
})
```

However, I am stuck with how to actually configure the plugin via an extension method. The only extension that is available seems to be `JacocoPluginExtension`. From there, I don't see a way how to add the `reports` part from build.gradle.

Is there some other mechanism besides extensions that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

'jacocoTestReport' is actually a task, so you can configure it like this:

```
    proj.tasks.getByName("jacocoTestReport", {
        reports {
            xml.required = true
        }
    })
```

If you'd like to dig deeper, it's class is [JacocoReport](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html), which has a
[JacocoReportsContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/tasks/JacocoReportsContainer.html) reports property, so you may use type safe property getters / setters from there, but IMHO the above solution is more like build.gradle, so it's more readable.